# Draggable only part of a series : highcharts

Tags: r, highcharts

I would like drag points when x is greater than 5.

Can anyone help me on that?

Example:

```
library("shiny")
library("highcharter")

ui <- shinyUI(
  fluidPage(
    column(width = 8, highchartOutput("hcontainer", height = "500px")),
    column(width = 4, textOutput("text"))
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {      

  a <- data.frame(b = LETTERS[1:10], c = 11:20, d = 21:30, e = 31:40)

  output$hcontainer <- renderHighchart({      

    canvasClickFunction <- JS("function(event) {Shiny.onInputChange('canvasClicked', [this.name, event.point.category]);}")
    legendClickFunction <- JS("function(event) {Shiny.onInputChange('legendClicked', this.name);}")

    highchart() %>% 
      hc_xAxis(categories = a$b) %>% 
      hc_add_serie(name = "c", data = a$c) %>%
      hc_add_serie(name = "d", data = a$d) %>% 
      hc_add_serie(name = "e", data = a$e) %>%
      hc_plotOptions(series = list(stacking = FALSE, events = list(click = canvasClickFunction, legendItemClick = legendClickFunction))) %>%
      hc_chart(type = "column")

  })      

  makeReactiveBinding("outputText")

  observeEvent(input$canvasClicked, {
    outputText <<- paste0("You clicked on series ", input$canvasClicked[1], " and the bar you clicked was from category ", input$canvasClicked[2], ".") 
  })

  observeEvent(input$legendClicked, {
    outputText <<- paste0("You clicked into the legend and selected series ", input$legendClicked, ".")
  })

  output$text <- renderText({
    outputText      
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Hi Bruno, and welcome to SO! Can you clarify what you mean by "drag points"?

Comment: For the example above, I want to be able change the values of the bars on the right side of letter "F" .

Comment: Uh, interactive in this high-charts style means tooltips, not value change, as far as I know.

Comment: Have you seen draggable-points plugin? Maybe you can use it to meet your requirements? http://jsfiddle.net/AyUbx/3320/